# #VALUE using the FILTER function in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I hear so many good things about the FILTER function in Excel, but I can't seem to get on with it. More often than not I end up with a #VALUE error. I'll usually get to the bottom of it, but this one has stumped me.

This is the formula:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1[#All],IFERROR((Sheet1[[#All],[Account]]=$D$1)*(Table2[[#All],[Duplicate 21711000]]=0),0))
```

I've put the IFERROR in because I thought perhaps a bunch of #N/A in the results could be causing an issue.

I've evaluated the Formula, and on the array on the Include side, everything seems to be working perfectly. The Boolean logic has worked, the 1s and 0s are in the right place to theoretically filter my list down to the few records I want to see. But when I click evaluate the final time, and it applies those 1s and 0s to the rows in the array, it results in the #VALUE error, and that's obviously all I can see in the cell.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

By the way, the point of this is to help a client who regularly pulls off a report from her accounting system, and then manually filters, copies and pastes the lines for new transactions onto separate tabs on her spreadsheet, over about 30 accounts. My plan is to use Power Query to bring the report into a tab in her spreadsheet, then use the Filter function to bring across the appropriate rows from the Power Query Table into each tab. That's the first criteria here.

I've created another table next to the PowerQuery table which uses a Count If to work out if that line has already been imported. So the second part of the criteria filters the list if the CountIf has registered a duplicate.

I can't just use PowerQuery everywhere, because she needs to then be able to add more columns and manipulate the data once it's been imported. So the final part of the job is to create a macro to copy > paste values, obviously copying the filter function into the row below first, ready for next month.

So Power Query imports all the data, Filter function extracts the specific data into each tab, and Macro locks in that data ready to be edited if need be.

If anyone can think of a better way of achieving the same result, I'm all ears.

Comment: Are you sure both arrays in the 1st parameter and the 2nd paramter are of the same size. I noticed you are comparing different tables in your boolean structure. Note `Sheet1[[#All]` could be of a different size to `Table2[[#All]`. If they differ you are going to indeed end up with an error for unsuccesfull parsing.

Comment: No they're not, is that important? That's why I end up with lots of N/As that I fixed with the IFERROR. I've overshot the second table in case the PowerQuery ever refreshes and gets longer, I didn't realise that was important. That seems to have fixed the problem though. Simple as that. Thanks.

Annoying though, as the criteria array ends up fine with all the blank rows ending up as 0s. In a perfect world that shouldn't matter. I'll need to think about it though, because if the first table does expands or shrink, the second table won't change with it.

Answer (score 1):

So thank you @JvdV, the simple answer was indeed that the two tables were of different sizes, and FILTER requires for them to be the same size.

This caused a follow up issue though that in order to count if I had any duplicates in the sheet, I couldn't go with plan A and use a separate table, because it wouldn't dynamically change it's height when the Power Query table was refreshed.

I looked into maybe incorporating the table into the Power Query in the first place with a custom column. But this would mean that the PowerQuery would end up with 39 additional columns, which would all be brought across by each FILTER function.

So instead I did this. I know this is very niche, so probably won't help anyone, but I'm very proud of myself and want to post it somewhere:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1[#All],IFERROR((Sheet1[[#All],[Account]]=$D$1)*IF((COUNTIF('21711000 (125006) Int rec'!$C:$C,Sheet1[[#All],[Document Number]]))=0,1,0),0))
```

(I probably don't need the IFERROR anymore, but it works, so I'm not going to touch it, and it might be safe just in case there ever are any errors).

So this uses the fact that Excel spills now rather than needing specific array functions. Before I made COUNTIF into a separate column, but now I'm putting it in here, and it naturally spills in the background, essentially creating that column within the formula. Then the IF changes any 0 to a TRUE (1), and any other number (my duplicates) to a FALSE (0), and everything works.

It actually creates a circular reference, because the Filter is in column C, but I think that's okay for my purposes, because I don't want it to include the results from the filter anyway. I suspected that might happen, but it seems to be working so far.

I hope that can help someone.

Comment: I lied. The circular reference did matter, as it refused to recalculate when any changes were made in the original PowerQuery table. So instead I used a Dynamic Named Range, using an OFFSET function. Rather inelegantly I've used just a column of dots off in column XFD as the Dynamic Range to get the count of rows, so it won't overlap the filter.